# Spring STS 'Spring boot cli script'/'Spring boot cli service' External tool configuration

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tools-4, sts

Tried to create 'Spring boot cli script' and 'Spring boot cli service' under eclipse external tool configuration. They both ended up with an error (Pic link below). Any suggestions on how this can resolved?

[External tool configuration image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvSdl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this is supported anymore. Ever since Groovy Eclipse is not part of STS there is no UI to launch spring boot cli Groovy scripts. However, you should still be able to do it via command line interface: `./spring run <groovy script>` Even in Eclipse UI you should be able to do it from the terminal view (i.e. cli in Eclipse view)

If you feel this use case is very important you could open an issue here https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues However, it appears to me more like the Groovy script launch config for boot CLI should rather be removed than